# How to allow specific values in my string

Tags: php

I want to replace space with `"|"` and i want only numbers and alphabets and star(*) in the sting

And i have tried `str_replace()` funtion but it replace the space with | , but i want to validate

```
echo $text= str_replace(' ','|', "This is some $123 Money");
```

output

```
This|is|some|$123|Money
```

what i expect is

```
This|is|some|123|Money
```

I don't want any other special characters in my output

Any Suggestions

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you want the value of a variable? In PHP variable names cannot start with numbers... that's why PHP is assuming 123 is not a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **preg_replace** to remove all special characters from your string.

**Example**

```
echo $text= str_replace(' ','|', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', '',"This is some $123 Money"));
```

**Output**

```
This|is|some|123|Money
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working demo for you: https://3v4l.org/M456J

```
<?php
$s = "This is some $123 Money";
$result = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "|", $s);
echo $result;
```

Output:

```
This|is|some|123|Money
```